# Firebase audience user count

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, audience

On tab Audience there is a column Users - hint on hover says:

```
Number of users in this audience that triggered events.
```

I have one audience already defined (defined as app_tracking_app_version contains 5.5.4) and if I select "Last 30 days" then I have like 409k users.
But if I select "Last 7 days" then I have like 443k users.

How it is possible, that by selecting shorter time range I'm getting more users?